# Delete storage in 'Other Volumes in Container'?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

**Hello,
can you guys help me**

[image]

**I did factory reset also I used OmniDiskSweeper did not help**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

‘Other Volumes in Container’ are other volumes independent from your currently booted operating system and its data volume.

In your case `diskutil list` shows `disk1s5` and `disk1s7` as additional Data volumes. Check the contents of these volumes in Finder (or with OmniDiskSweeper pointed at these volumes instead).